# "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" While running ECM Architect Tutorial 1 for Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

I am doing the [Tutorial #1 for Alfresco](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html#lets-run-it) from the ECM Architech website.

Maven downloads all dependencies and compiles the project. Docker also starts. But eventually, it gets stuck with the below error stack:

```
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       | 2022-04-18 04:00:14.309 ERROR (searcherExecutor-7-thread-1-processing-x:alfresco) [   x:alfresco] o.a.s.t.AbstractTracker Model tracking failed for core: alfresco
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       | java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.executeMethod(AbstractHttpClient.java:135)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.sendRemoteRequest(AbstractHttpClient.java:111)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.httpclient.HttpClientFactory$DefaultHttpClient.sendRequest(HttpClientFactory.java:430)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1178)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:291)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:249)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:271)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.lifecycle.SolrCoreLoadRegistration.registerForCore(SolrCoreLoadRegistration.java:110)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.alfresco.solr.lifecycle.SolrCoreLoadListener.newSearcher(SolrCoreLoadListener.java:44)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$getSearcher$15(SolrCore.java:2249)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
docker-maven-sdk-tutorial-ass-1       |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
d
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please check that all the container started properly. This is happening when Repo container not started.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this was happening due to an issue with Docker on my M1 Macbook Air. I ran the same tutorial on a Windows Machine and on Ubuntu (both on AMD), and it worked perfectly.